# Row count wrong in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rows

I have a repeating list of dates which I used the unique function on, called it "u".  Now I am trying to get the length of this list but I am clearing getting wrong answer, 506, instead of what comes out when I simply call "u" which is 738.

```
typeof(u)
[1] "list"
class(u)
[1] "data.frame"
nrow(u)
[1] 506

733 2014-01-02
734 2014-01-03
737 2014-01-06
738 2014-01-07
```

Comment: Did you notice that the row names skipped 735 and 736? What could you infer from that?

Comment: Obviously I did not notice, but thanks

Comment: "Clearly" there are in fact 506 rows in your `u` .  How did you arrive at that count of 738 rows?  Did you print and count them all?  Try this:  `u[507]` and see if that returns something or not.

Comment: Is `u` a subset of a larger set?  It seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you seem to have a data.frame with 506 rows that skips some numbers and might have 738 as highest number. If you really want to get 738, you can do:

```
max(u[1])
```